# How to get the index of the node that is currently editing within the contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div, and inside this div, I have 3 nodes

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true"><span>dear</span>world<span>hello</span></div>
```

in this case, if we use code below:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('editable').childNodes)
```

we will have something like `[span, text, span]`. How can I get the index of the node which is being editing. For example, if the user is editing the word `dear`, I should get the index "`0`", because it's the first node, if the user is editing the word `hello`, I should get the index "`2`"

I have a function that is able to return the actual node I'm editing, but I'm not sure would help. see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kesongxie/xvjbwfbt/1/).

Comment: you are almost there, use your getEditingNode function to always return the parentNode instead of returning a text node. Then go through all document.getElementById('editable').childNodes and compare them with the returned node to get the index

Comment: @AlexBarroso, if we are always returning the parentNode, when the user is editing word "world"(which is a text node), then the parent node will be the div with id "editable", which is undesirable, right?

Comment: Well, yes, what you need to do is try to return the parent element who is child of the editable node.

Comment: What should happen if the word `world` is edited ?

Comment: @adeneo it should return 1 as the index, because it's the second node

Comment: But in the question, you say `hello` should return the index `1`? Are you confused ?

Comment: @adeneo, I'm so stupid, just fixed the error. So there are 3 nodes in the div with id editable, the first node is a span, the second is text node, the third is a span, I need to get the index of which one is currently being editing

Comment: So like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xvjbwfbt/5/

Comment: @adeneo, brilliant, so the idea is to wrap those text nodes into spans, and count their positions?

Comment: That's at least what I did, wrapping in spans makes no difference to the user, and makes it a lot easier to get the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap the text nodes in spans, so you have element nodes only, and just use jQuery's `index()` to get the index

```
$('#editable').on('keydown', function(e){
    var _node = document.getSelection().anchorNode; 
    var node  = _node.nodeType == 3 ? _node.parentNode : _node;
    var index = $(this).children().index(node);

    console.log( index ); // output index

}).contents().each(function(i, node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        $(node).wrap('<span />');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xvjbwfbt/5/)

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not going to actual wrap the span and modify the actual content on the page, but I can do it via some inner processings and get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit simpler of a way to get what you want:

```
var node = null;
node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
node = ((node.nodeType===1)?node:node.parentNode);    

var idx = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(node.parentNode.childNodes,node);
```

The `idx` will be given correctly as you want.

Comment: if the html is  <div id = "editable" contenteditable = "true"><span>dear </span>world<span> hello</span> flower</div> , when I edit flower, the index is still 1, which is not right

Comment: @KesongXie Indeed. Wrapping text nodes in a span will resolve it as Adeneo has pointed out.